# Jackson deserialize two different Json representations in one POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to deserialize two different representations in the same pojo object, for example when optional translations can be returned.

For example, this is my pojo:

```
class LightCustomer {
  enum TITLE {
    Mr, Mrs, Ms
  }
  public TITLE title;
  public String titleLabel;
}
```

No problem with first available representation :

```
{
  "title": "Mrs"
}
```

My second representation with translation :

```
{
  "title": {
    "value": "Mrs",
    "label": "Madame"
  }
}
```

There is an way to :

- deserialize "title" or "title.value" in LightCustomer.setTitle() ?
- deserialize "title.label" in LightCustomer.setTitleLabel() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JacksonRootName` for the second representation.

```
@JsonRootName(value = "title")
class LightCustomer {
  enum TITLE {
    Mr, Mrs, Ms
  }
  public TITLE title;
  public String label;
}
```

Configure the ObjectMapper instance with

```
mapper.configure(Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true); //version 1.9
```

or

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true); //version 2
```

You can use different ObjectMapper instance for example. I'm not entirely sure if it is a good idea though. Perhaps a better way: create custom serializer/deserializer that allow both representation to be handled by a single instance of ObjectMapper.